# Issue caching python dependencies in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, github, pip, github-actions

I have the following steps in a github action:

```
steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Cache dependencies
        id: pip-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~.cache/pip
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pip-

      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.pip-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
     
      - name: run mypy
        run: mypy .
```

The caching works fine, but when a cache hit occurs, and I try to run mypy, it fails with:

```
Run mypy .
/home/runner/work/_temp/9887df5b-d5cc-46d7-90e1-b884d8c49272.sh: line 1: mypy: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

The whole point of caching dependencies is so I don't have to install them every time I run the workflow. How do I use the cached dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only caching **source tarballs** and **binary wheels** downloaded by `pip`. You're *not* caching:

- **Installed Python packages** (i.e., the `site-packages/` subdirectory of the active Python interpreter).
- **Installed entry points** (i.e., executable commands residing in the current `${PATH}`).

That isn't necessarily a bad thing. Merely downloading assets tends to consume a disproportionate share of scarce GitHub Actions (GA) minutes; caching  assets trivially alleviates that issue.

In other words, remove the `if: steps.pip-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` line to restore your GitHub Actions (GA) workflow to sanity.

### But... I Want to Cache Installed Packages!

**Challenge accepted.** This is feasible – albeit more fragile. I'd advise just caching `pip` downloads unless you've profiled the `pip install` command to be a significant installation bottleneck.

Let's assume that you still want to do this. In this case, something resembling the following snippet should get you where you want to go:

```yaml
  - uses: 'actions/setup-python@v2'
    with:
      # CAUTION: Replace this hardcoded "3.7" string with the
      # major and minor version of your desired Python interpreter.
      python-version: "3.7"
  - uses: 'actions/cache@v2'
    id: cache
    with:
      # CAUTION: Replace this hardcoded "python3.7" dirname with
      # the dirname providing your desired Python interpreter.
      path: ${{ env.pythonLocation }}/lib/python3.7/site-packages/*
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
        ${{ runner.os }}-
```

As noted, you'll want to manually replace the hardcoded `3.7` and `python3.7` substrings above with something specific to your use case. That's one of several reasons why this is dangerously fragile. <s>Another is that the `${{ env.pythonLocation }}` environment variable set by the `setup-python` GitHub Action has been [infamously undocumented for several years](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/78). `</gulp>`</s> (`env.pythonLocation` documentation was added from [v4.0.0](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/releases/tag/v4.0.0).)

In theory, adding the above directly under your existing `uses: actions/cache@v2` list item should suffice. Good luck and Godspeed as you travel into the terrifying unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I noticed shortly after posting this that removing the `if: steps.pip-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` fixes the issue. I added it because I saw that the pip output was saying `installing dependencies`, but didn't look closely enough to see it was saying `installing cached dependencies`... always read your logs closely folks.