# Caching python in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, caching, pip, github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to cache the Python installation and dependencies in "Self-hosted" GitHub Action, the problem is the restore of cached pip is taking too long and results in timeout, and I could not figure out why.
What I checked:
-> [Issue caching python dependencies in GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896173/issue-caching-python-dependencies-in-github-actions)
-> [Github Actions don't reuse cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412207/github-actions-dont-reuse-cache)
-> [Cache is not being correctly loaded in Github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655514/cache-is-not-being-correctly-loaded-in-github-actions)

in addition to the official Cache repo Docs on GitHub. below is the config used

```
- name: Set up Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@v4
  id: python311
  with:
    python-version: '3.11.8'
    cache: 'pip'
    cache-dependency-path: 'modules/**/requirements*.txt'

- name: Cache Python dependencies
  uses: actions/cache@v4.0.2
  with:
    path: ~/.cache/pip
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements*.txt') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-pip-

- name: Cache Python interpreter
  uses: actions/cache@v4.0.2
  with:
    path: ${{ env.pythonLocation }} #/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-python-${{ hashFiles('/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-python-


- name: Install requirements
  run: |
    mkdir -p .output
    pip install -r modules/localfiles/requirements.test.txt
```

The output:

```bash
Version 3.11.8 was not found in the local cache
  Version 3.11.8 is available for downloading
  Download from "https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases/download/3.11.8-7809691605/python-3.11.8-linux-20.04-x64.tar.gz"
  Extract downloaded archive
  /usr/bin/tar xz --warning=no-unknown-keyword -C /runner/_work/_temp/ee3bccf9-3f77-4c32-97e6-429f1d6adb00 -f /runner/_work/_temp/9f59a8fb-fb9d-4d39-b3df-ffb7b7288fac
  Execute installation script
  Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
  Creating Python hostedtoolcache folder...
  Create Python 3.11.8 folder
  Copy Python binaries to hostedtoolcache folder
  Create additional symlinks (Required for the UsePythonVersion Azure Pipelines task and the setup-python GitHub Action)
  Upgrading pip...
  Looking in links: /tmp/tmpr1ai5afl
  Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages (65.5.0)
  Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages (24.0)
  Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
  Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 299.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing collected packages: pip
  Successfully installed pip-24.0
  Create complete file
  Successfully set up CPython (3.11.8)
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/bin/pip cache dir
/home/runner/.cache/pip
Received 0 of 57628253 (0.0%), 0.0 MBs/sec
Received 25165824 of 57628253 (43.7%), 12.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 17.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 12.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 10.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 8.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 7.3 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 6.4 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 5.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 5.1 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 4.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 4.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 3.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 3.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 3.4 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 3.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 3.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.4 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.3 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.1 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 2.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.4 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.4 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.3 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.3 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.3 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.2 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.1 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.1 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.1 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.1 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 1.0 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.9 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.8 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.7 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.6 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Received 53433949 of 57628253 (92.7%), 0.5 MBs/sec
Warning: Failed to restore: The operation cannot be completed in timeout.
pip cache is not found
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do manual caching outside of setup-python, it should do the caching for you already.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Even if I remove the caching step it keeps freezing